# Why after adding php code, my layout is gone bad?

Tags: php, html, css, templates, layout

I have a problem with my layout.
When I add php code on html, some of the HTML tags begin to move. I want to create a card with information. It has header(some kind of image) and body(title - categorie - text). When I tried it without php, just with random text, everything was fine. But, after adding php code, my header and body divided.

**html code without the php**:

```
<a class="card_article" href="#">
    <div class="card_header">
        <img src="img/avatar2.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="card_body">
        <p class="bid_link">Название статьи</p>
        <p>Категория: Программирование</p>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="go-corner" href="{% url 'places:detail' i.id %}">
        <div class="go-arrow">
            →
        </div>
    </div>
</a>
```

[image: that is the example of result of html without php]

**html with php code**:

```
<?php 
    $articles = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM `articles` WHERE `categories_id` = 3   ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 10");
?>
<?php 
    while ( $art = mysqli_fetch_assoc($articles) )
    {
        ?>
        <a class="card_article" href="#">
            <div class="card_header">
                <img src="style/images/<?php echo $art['image']; ?>" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="card_body">
                <a class="bid_link" href="/article.php?id=<?php echo $art['id']?>"><?php echo $art['title']; ?></a>
                <?php
                    $categories = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM `articles_categories`");
                ?>
                <?php 
                    $cat = mysqli_fetch_assoc($categories)
                ?>
                <?php
                    $art_cat = false;
                    foreach( $categories as $cat )
                    {
                        if( $cat['id'] == $art['categories_id'] )
                        {
                            $art_cat = $cat;
                            break;
                        }
                    } 
                ?>
                <p class="under">Категория: <a href="/categotie.php?id=<?php echo $art_cat['id']; ?>"><?php echo $art_cat['title']?></a></p>
                <p class="under"><?php echo mb_substr($art['text'], 0, 60, 'utf-8');?> ...</p>
            </div>
            <div class="go-corner" href="{% url 'places:detail' i.id %}">
                <div class="go-arrow">
                    →
                </div>
            </div>
        </a>
        <?php
    }
?>
```

[image: Now that is the result with adding php]

Also, I noticed in the google viewing code, that my html code (which I wrote myself) doesn't match with code which is in the google code viewing.
[image: You can see it here]

Comment: Thanks for cooperating, but it didn't help.

Comment: I had added new descriptions, please watch it. I will appreciate any of your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can begin to make your code simpler, ie remove redundant php parenthesis.

Here's a lighter version of the exact same code

```
<?php 
    $articles = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM `articles` WHERE `categories_id` = 3   ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 10");
    while ( $art = mysqli_fetch_assoc($articles) )
    {
        ?>
        <a class="card_article" href="#">
            <div class="card_header">
                <img src="style/images/<?php echo $art['image']; ?>" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="card_body">
                <a class="bid_link" href="/article.php?id=<?php echo $art['id'] . "\">" . $art['title'] . "</a>";
                    $categories = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM `articles_categories`");
                    $cat = mysqli_fetch_assoc($categories);
                    $art_cat = false;
                    foreach( $categories as $cat )
                    {
                        if( $cat['id'] == $art['categories_id'] )
                        {
                            $art_cat = $cat;
                            break;
                        }
                    } 
                ?>
                <p class="under">Категория: <a href="/categotie.php?id=<?php echo $art_cat['id'] . "\">" . $art_cat['title'] . "</a></p>"; ?>
                <p class="under"><?php echo mb_substr($art['text'], 0, 60, 'utf-8');?> ...</p>
            </div>
            <div class="go-corner" href="{% url 'places:detail' i.id %}">
                <div class="go-arrow">
                    →
                </div>
            </div>
        </a>
        <?php
    }
?>
```

Then, strictly HTML speaking, your manual and generated codes aren't the same.
You have multiple links in your code which aren't present in your manual example, ie `<p class="bid_link">Название статьи</p>` becomes an anchor in your code.

You should remove all anchors and generate the **exact** same code than the manual written one, then add step by step the anchors until you find the culprit.

There's probably something in your generated code that changes the CSS.